# Search and replace github url strings using git grep

Tags: git, grep, xargs

I have a bunch of git repos and need to search and replace a url string for the following conditions:

- Http should be changed to https, if https is present already then leave it as it is
- Search for "some domain" (it may or may not be present) followed by a predefined search string, replace the finding with "some domain" (if it exists) followed by changed predefined search string

So for example given the following URLs:

```
http://abc.repos.dev.com
http://repos.dev.com
```

Should return

```
https://abc.repos.prod.com
https://repos.prod.com
```

Where `repos.dev.com` should be replaced by `repos.prod.com` and `abc` is some arbitrary domain.

There are a bunch of files that need to be scanned and their URL contents replaced. I had some luck with a simpler solution to a simpler requirement (http, https or arbitrary domains were not involved) using:

```
git grep -l repos.dev.com | xargs sed -i '' -e 's/repos.dev.com/repos.prod.com/g'
```

I have tried the following:

```
git grep -lE '(http|https)://.*?repos.dev.com' | xargs sed -i '' -e 's/(http|https):\/\/.*?repos.dev.com/https:\/\/.*repos.prod.com/g'
```

But I think there are a couple of issues, one thing I can notice is the global replace might not be picking up "arbitrary" domain url prefix prior to the required changed string (is that even possible?)

Would anyone be able to shed some light into what I am doing wrong?

Comment: one issue I can easily see is that both grep/sed do not support non-greedy, i.e `.*?` won't work

Comment: also, you can use `https?` instead of `(http|https)`

Comment: to be safe remove the non-greedy and search for characters that can be in a domain like `[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]*`

Comment: unfortunately, this question is too broad to get any kind of help. you'll need to provide more context and concrete examples.